# Swift 3: Set variable in if/else statement

Tags: if-statement, swift3, let

I want to define a dynamic variable for my alert box. I'm getting a json from my server, like ok, error, username_in_use, etc etc.

```
let response = parseJSON["message"] as? String

if response == "username_in_use" {
    let error_msg = "Username in already use!"
} else if response == "email_in_use" {
    let error_msg = "Email address in already use!"
} else {
    let error_msg = "Unknown Error!"
}

alertView.showTitle(
    alertTitle: error_msg
)
```

But i'm getting this message:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'error_msg'
```

How can I set a dynamic value for my alert title?

Thanks for help and sorry my poor english.

Comment: `let error_msg: String` above the if conditions and remove the `let` from inside the conditions brackets

Comment: Before the `if ...`:  `let error_msg = ""` in `if ...`: `error_msg = ...`.

Comment: Again, no need to declare it as variable as suggested in both answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the scope of error_msg is limited to the blocks within the if statement.
You could declare error_msg outside of the if blocks scope, e.g.

```
let response = parseJSON["message"] as? String
var error_msg:String

if response == "username_in_use" {
    error_msg = "Username in already use!"
} else if response == "email_in_use" {
    error_msg = "Email address in already use!"
} else {
    error_msg = "Unknown Error!"
}

alertView.showTitle(
    alertTitle: error_msg
)
```

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a Switch statement.

Answer (score 3):

This is the perfect use case for a switch statement:

```
let errorMsg: String

switch response {
case "username_in_use": errorMsg = "Username in already use!"
case "email_in_use": errorMsg = "Email address in already use!"
default: errorMsg = "Unknown Error!"
}
```

Comment: You can also use let instead of var

Comment: @LeoDabus Oh interesting, nice!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use the possibly existing (`Any`?) value corresponding to key `"message"` in the `parseJSON` dictionary for direct further processing/translation, you needn't necessarily store this value, but can use it inline to proceed with processing it to a valid error message. E.g., using `switch` statement:

```
var error_msg: String = "Unknown error"
switch parseJSON["message"] {
    case let val as String where val == "username_in_use": error_msg = "Username in already use!"
    case let val as String where val == "email_in_use": error_msg = "Email address in already use!"
    case _: ()
}

// ...
alertView.showTitle(
    alertTitle: error_msg
)
```

Or, make use of a helper dictionary to map the JSON `"message"` codes (values) to error messages, readily allowing use of the `nil` coalescing operator to supply a the default (unknown error) message:

```
let error_msgs = [
    "username_in_use" : "Username in already use!",
    "email_in_use"    : "Email address in already use!"]

let error_msg = error_msgs[parseJSON["message"] as? String ?? ""] ?? "Unknown Error!"

// ...
alertView.showTitle(
    alertTitle: error_msg
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the `let error_msg` outside the if statement so that it is visible when you pass it to the alert.

```
   let response = parseJSON["message"] as? String

   var error_msg = ""

   if response == "username_in_use" {
       error_msg = "Username in already use!"
   } else if response == "email_in_use" {
       error_msg = "Email address in already use!"
   } else {
       error_msg = "Unknown Error!"
   }

   alertView.showTitle(alertTitle: error_msg)
```